# Integrating Google Analytics with xamarin android app

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, google-analytics

I am working on an Android app using Xamarin. I have tried to follow [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/) tutorial from Google in which they ask me to edit the `build.gradle` file but I don't have this file in my solution (maybe because I am in Xamarin, I don't know). So I have searched for an other tutorial especially for Xamarin user.
I have found [this](https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2015/07/06/lets-add-google-analytics-to-your-xamarin-android-app-_/) one and those are my code till now:

```
public class GAService
{
    public string TrackingId = "XX-XXXXXXXX-X";

    private static GoogleAnalytics GAInstance;
    private static Tracker GATracker;

    #region Instantiation ...
    private static GAService thisRef;
    private GAService()
    {

    }

    public static GAService GetGASInstance()
    {
        if (thisRef == null)

            thisRef = new GAService();
        return thisRef;
    }
    #endregion

    public void Initialize(Context AppContext)
    {
        GAInstance = GoogleAnalytics.GetInstance(AppContext.ApplicationContext);
        GAInstance.SetLocalDispatchPeriod(10);

        GATracker = GAInstance.NewTracker(TrackingId);
        GATracker.EnableExceptionReporting(true);
        GATracker.EnableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
        GATracker.EnableAutoActivityTracking(true);
    }

    public void Track_App_Page(String PageNameToTrack)
    {
        GATracker.SetScreenName(PageNameToTrack);
        GATracker.Send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().Build());
    }

    public void Track_App_Event(String GAEventCategory, String EventToTrack)
    {
        HitBuilders.EventBuilder builder = new HitBuilders.EventBuilder();
        builder.SetCategory(GAEventCategory);
        builder.SetAction(EventToTrack);
        builder.SetLabel("AppEvent");

        GATracker.Send(builder.Build());
    }

    public void Track_App_Exception(String ExceptionMessageToTrack, Boolean isFatalException)
    {
        HitBuilders.ExceptionBuilder builder = new HitBuilders.ExceptionBuilder();
        builder.SetDescription(ExceptionMessageToTrack);
        builder.SetFatal(isFatalException);

        GATracker.Send(builder.Build());
    }
}
```

I am getting the same error in three places in the above code, the first is here: `private static GoogleAnalytics GAInstance;` which says `The namescape 'GoogleAnalytics' could not be found`.
The second is here:`private static Tracker GATracker;` saying `The namescape 'Tracker' could not be found`.
The third is here: `HitBuilders.EventBuilder builder = new HitBuilders.EventBuilder();` saying `The namescape 'HitBuilders' could not be found`.
Any solutions for my problem ?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [this](http://mariuspukas.com/how-to-add-google-analytics-xamarin-forms-android-ios/) tutorial. Specifically the first 2 points where, on Android, you will need to install the [Google Play Services Analytics](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Analytics/) NuGet package to get access to those classes.